# Load baked particle system cache in blender

Tags: python, blender, particle-system

I am trying to programatically load the baked files for a particle system in blender. I managed to load the files with no problem for fluid simulations, but the particle system uses a different bake / cache system and I got stuck trying to load it for this.

Here's the code I am using:

```
pts = []

for i in scn.objects:
    for j in i.modifiers:
        if j.__class__.__name__ == "ParticleSystemModifier":
            pts.append(j.particle_system)


file_start_particle = 'tt'
file_index = '00'

for m in pts:
    m.point_cache.filepath = bake_file_path
    m.point_cache.name = file_start_particle
    m.point_cache.index = int(file_index)
    m.point_cache.use_external = True
    m.point_cache.use_disk_cache = True
```

However, this results in a black image. No error is being displayed at the console and the rendering seems to be doing its thing.

Any idea how I can load the cache files so they are used and the render works?

Thanks